# Get other players moves into flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Currently I have made a flash/as3 Snake game which I want to somehow make it online. So that players can all play together online at the same time.

But my question is, how can I get the informations of the other players? To the players game?

Like when someone move down/up/left or right, how can I get that to show on the other players screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a server that all players are connected to, either via persistent [Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) or [RTMP](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html) connection. Basically your SWF sends information about the players move to the server, which then passes it to all the other connected players.

You can either build such a server by your own, or use existing technoligies like for example [FMS](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), [SmartFox](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/) or [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) ([here you can find some more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol)).